# Android: onClick Between Views and utilizing Asynctask

Tags: android, rss, onclick, android-asynctask

My project that I've spent almost 40hrs on is almost complete, but I have one last task to accomplish.  My previous problem what that when users clicked to pull up a news RSS feed that app would sometimes hang because it both tried to load the activity and the feed at the same time.  This was resolved with asynctask.

Now along with this, I have four buttons that switch between different feeds and essentially just modifying the view.  This eliminates reloading the screen or new activity.  Well, when I initially fire up this activity, the asynctask works exactly like I want, but it's not as simple as copying pasting to each of the different views at the bottom.  How do I implement asynctask under each of those different buttons/views.  You'll see the onClick at the bottom.

Here is the asynctask section.

```
public class RssLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          displayRss();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          preReadRss();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         }

         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          readRss();
          return null;
         }

        }
```

**And below here is the onClick section.  Obviously with the above i have each readRss, preReadRSS, etc...in the right places in the initial activity, but why won't Java allow me to place these same asynctask tasks in the onClick section?  I just don't know enought about modifiers yet to know how to place them.  Still learning a lot.**

public void onClick(View v) {

```
if (v == hawknation) {


    try {

          URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.rss.com/feed");
          SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
          SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
          XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
          RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
          myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
          InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
          myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

          myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (SAXException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
         }}


   {

         if (myRssFeed!=null)
         {
          TextView feedTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
          TextView feedDescribtion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feeddescribtion);
          TextView feedPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedpubDate);
          TextView feedLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.feedlink);
          feedTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getTitle());
          feedDescribtion.setText(myRssFeed.getDescription());
          feedPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getPubdate());
          feedLink.setText(myRssFeed.getLink());

          MyCustomAdapter adapter =
           new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row, myRssFeed.getList());
          setListAdapter(adapter);

         }       
     }
```

Comment: Why are you using a public class `RssLoadingTask` instead of having an  inner one?

Comment: You should explain little better what your problem is and why you can't put `AsyncTask` in `onClick`.

Comment: @Francesco - I am pretty Novice.  How would I modify it?

Comment: Ok, I'll try again.  I have asynctask running at the beginning of the activity to load my initial activity.  Then down below you see an onClick event.  When someone clicks one of four buttons, it brings up a new view, which is also a new feed.   Right now it just switches to the new feed, it doesn't do that asynctask.  I did this so that would kick off an entire new activity/screen to open the next feed.  Makes it seemless, just like USA Today App or Fox News.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using my view in question.  I just switch between views by opening a different activity on each button.